# .Click function trigger just one time in java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read many questions here but not find a solution for problem.

I have one page which has two dates and one text box. When I click on text box the difference of two dates in days will show on text box. But when I change the dates and click on text box it doesn't work.

Code

```
$('#totalNoOfLeave').click(function(){

    var date1 = new Date($('#leaveStartDate').getValue());
    var date2 = new Date($('#leaveEndingDate').getValue());
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
    $('#totalNoOfLeave').setValue(diffDays);

});
```

Please help.

Comment: I think the event should be `focus`

Comment: I can put alert inside function to debug. But also alert trigger once.

Comment: Could you create a minimal example to reproduce the problem, then?

Comment: I am using ProcessMaker, and here focus event is not trigger. It works with .click

Comment: Can you please tell me the way to call .click function whenever click on object in same page

Comment: Please try variations of your code. Examples [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/). For example, have you tried: `$( "#totalNoOfLeave" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Checking it works" );
});`. Also, show us the results.

Comment: Btw, please add your HTML code to your question. Have a feeling you might be mixing `id` with `class` attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this :

```
$('body').on('click', '#totalNoOfLeave', function () {

var date1 = new Date($('#leaveStartDate').getValue());
var date2 = new Date($('#leaveEndingDate').getValue());
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
$('#totalNoOfLeave').setValue(diffDays);

});
```

Comment: thank you very much. Yes its working but I replace 'body' with form id